# Error: Page is not found: favo.html

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui, monaca

I have 4 files 
index.html 
page1.html 
page2.html 
page3.html

Here's my code...

```
page3.html

<ons-page>
<ons-tabbar>
  <ons-tab page="home.html" active="true">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-home"></ons-icon>
    <span style="font-size: 14px">Home</span>
  </ons-tab>
  <ons-tab page="favo.html" active="true">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-star"></ons-icon>
    <span style="font-size: 14px">Favorite</span>
  </ons-tab>
  <ons-tab page="settings.html" active="true">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-social-twitter"></ons-icon>
    <span style="font-size: 14px">Bird</span>
  </ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>



<ons-template id="home.html">
  <p>Green home</p>
  <p>White home</p>
  <p>Pink home</p>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="favo.html">
  <p>Your favorite music.</p>
  <p>Your favorite food.</p>
  <p>Your favorite toy.</p>
  <p>Your favorite snack.</p>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="settings.html" >
  <div  ng-app="magic_land"  >
  <div   ng-controller="morning">
      <p> Cindy, {{greetings}} </p>
      <p> Alice, {{greetings}} </p>
      <p> Jessica, {{greetings}} </p>
      <p> {{2+8}} </p>
  </div>
  </div>
</ons-template>

</ons-page>
```

Why do i get this error?

```
Error: Page is not found: favo.html
```

Then i swapped into this...

```
<ons-template id="favo.html">
  <p>Your favorite music.</p>
  <p>Your favorite food.</p>
  <p>Your favorite toy.</p>
  <p>Your favorite snack.</p>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="home.html">
  <p>Green home</p>
  <p>White home</p>
  <p>Pink home</p>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="settings.html" >
  <div  ng-app="magic_land"  >
    <div   ng-controller="morning">
        <p> Cindy, {{greetings}} </p>
    </div>

    <div   ng-controller="afternoon">
        <p> Cindy, {{greetings}} </p>
    </div>

    <div   ng-controller="evening">
        <p> Cindy, {{greetings}} </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</ons-template>
```

Now im getting this error...

```
Page is not found: home.html
```

The 2nd position seems cursed.

............................................... 
 
............................................... 
 
...............................................

Here's the other files.

```
index.html

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-csp>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/winstore-jscompat.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesshet" href="components/monaca-onsenui/js/angular/angular-csp.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script>
        //ons.bootstrap();

        var magic_land = ons.bootstrap('magic_land', ['onsen']);

        magic_land.controller
        (
          "morning" ,
          function($scope)
          {
            $scope.greetings = "Rise and shine!" ;
          }
        ) ;

        magic_land.controller
        (
          "afternoon" ,
          function($scope)
          {
            $scope.greetings = "Good afternoon!" ;
          }
        ) ;

        magic_land.controller
        (
          "evening" ,
          function($scope)
          {
            $scope.greetings = "Good night. Sleep well." ;
          }
        ) ;

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ons-navigator var="captain" page="page3.html">
    </ons-navigator> 
</body>
</html>
```

.................

```
page1.html

<ons-page>
<ons-scroller>

    <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="center">This is page ONE</div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <div style="text-align: center">
        <br>
        <ons-button
            ng-click="captain.pushPage('page3.html')">
            Push It
        </ons-button>
        <br>

        <ons-list>
          <ons-list-header>Fruits</ons-list-header>
          <ons-list-item>Apple</ons-list-item>
          <ons-list-item>Banana</ons-list-item>
          <ons-list-item> {{5+5}} </ons-list-item>
        </ons-list>

        <br>

        Party <ons-switch checked></ons-switch>
    </div>

</ons-scroller>
</ons-page>
```

....................

```
page2.html

<ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Backware</ons-back-button></div>
        <div class="center">You are in Page TWO</div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <div style="text-align: center">

        <h1>Hello there!</h1>
        <ons-button
            ng-click="captain.popPage()">
          Pop Corn {{5+5}}
        </ons-button>

    </div>
</ons-page>
```

Didnt find a solution. But i found a workaround. 
As i said, 2nd & 4th template are cursed. So, i created dummy_1 and dummy_2 to take the curse. 
^_^ . Thats a smiley!

Change page3.html like below.

```
page3.html (workaround)

<body>
<ons-page>

<ons-tabbar>
  <ons-tab page="home.html" active="true">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-home"></ons-icon>
    <span style="font-size: 14px">Home</span>
  </ons-tab>
  <ons-tab page="favo.html" active="true">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-star"></ons-icon>
    <span style="font-size: 14px">Favorite</span>
  </ons-tab>
  <ons-tab page="settings.html" active="true">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-social-twitter"></ons-icon>
    <span style="font-size: 14px">Bird</span>
  </ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>

</ons-page>

<ons-template id="favo.html">
  <p>Your favorite music.</p>
  <p>Your favorite food.</p>
  <p>Your favorite toy.</p>
  <p>Your favorite snack.</p>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="dummy_1.html">
  <p></p>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="home.html">
  <p>Green home</p>
  <p>White home</p>
  <p>Pink home</p>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id = "dummy_2">
  <p></p>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="settings.html" >
  <div  ng-app="magic_land"  >
    <div   ng-controller="morning">
        <p> Cindy, {{greetings}} </p>
    </div>

    <div   ng-controller="afternoon">
        <p> Cindy, {{greetings}} </p>
    </div>

    <div   ng-controller="evening">
        <p> Cindy, {{greetings}} </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</ons-template>


</body>
```

Here's the tabs in action, show as gif video. 
http://postimg.org/image/vin7bak3x/

Comment: errr, if your workaround is truly the only way to make this work, there definitely should be a bug report filed on the project page.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're putting the `<ons-template>` tags inside the `<ons-page>` tag.

Instead try to put the templates at the body:

```
<body>
  <ons-tabbar>
    ...
  </ons-tabbar>

  <ons-template id="favo.html">
    ...
  </ons-template>

  <ons-template id="home.html">
    ...
  </ons-template>

  ...
</body>
```

Comment: i did what you said, and replaced <ons-page> with <body>. Still not working. @andreas-argelius

Comment: I mean you should put the templates as direct descendants to the body tag in your index.html.

Comment: Just a guess... shouldn´t you put an ons-page tag inside every template if you use them as pages in your tab menu?

Comment: Done. Put the templates as direct descendants, but still not working. @andreas-argelius

Comment: Didnt matter whether it templates was inside or outside the ons-page, i still got the same error.

Comment: I found a workaround, not exactly a correct solution. Look up.

Comment: Using my workaround, the code now works. But im still open for other solutions. Please post it if you find out. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my exact syntax for a split view I have as far as setting my pages. Hopefully the syntax helps for individual pages. This works well for me

```
    <ons-split-view
        var="app.splitView"
        secondary-page="secondary.html"
        main-page="page1.html"
        main-page-width="40%"
        collapse="portrait">


    <ons-template id="page1.html">
        <ons-page>
        <ons-tabbar>
            <ons-tab page="books.html" icon="ion-ios-bookmarks" label="Books" active="true" onclick="app.splitView.setSecondaryPage('secondary.html')"></ons-tab>
            <ons-tab page="topics.html" icon="ion-android-globe" label="Topics" onclick="app.splitView.setSecondaryPage('secondary.html')"></ons-tab>
            <ons-tab page="espanol.html" icon="ion-ios-color-filter" label="Español" onclick="app.splitView.setSecondaryPage('triple.html')"></ons-tab>
        </ons-tabbar>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

    <ons-template id="secondary.html">
        <ons-page>
            <ons-tabbar>
      <ons-tabbar-item page="split/bible.html" label="Bible" icon="fa fa-book" active="true"></ons-tabbar-item>
      <ons-tabbar-item page="split/browser.html" label="Browser" icon="fa fa-globe"></ons-tabbar-item>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

<ons-template id="triple.html">
    <ons-page>
        <ons-tabbar>
  <ons-tabbar-item page="biblia/gene.html" label="Bible" icon="fa fa-book" active="true"></ons-tabbar-item>
  <ons-tabbar-item page="split/espbrowser.html" label="Browser" icon="fa fa-globe"></ons-tabbar-item>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
    </ons-split-view>
```